# Probability of toughness of a metal

Tags: probability

The toughness of a metal has a gaussian distribution with avarage 70 and standard deviation of 3. Suppose that we denote by m the average of a poblation of this metal.We want to make sure that our average of metals does not differ from m more than 0.5 with a probability of 98%. How many metals do we have to study?

Thanks for your help I am struggling a lot with this problem.

Comment: Would you mind adding your work so far on the problem?

Comment: The standard error $E=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n} $ and I think that I have that E=0.5, but I don't want the error to be standard, I want a probability of 98% and the standard error is 68% I believe.

Comment: I think your are confusing _standard error_ and _standard deviation._ In a normal distribution about 68% of the probability is within one _standard deviation_ on either side of the mean. (Sometimes this is called the Empirical Rule.) See my Answer for what I believe you are asking. Please leave a Comment if that is not it. (_Poblation_ of metal is not exactly a statistical term.)

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your question as follows: You have observations $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$
randomly sampled from a population distributed as $Norm(\mu = 70, \sigma=3).$
Denote the sample mean by $\bar X,$ which has distribution $Norm(\mu=70,\sigma=3/\sqrt{n}).$ You seek $P(|\bar X - 70| \le 0.5) = .98.$

This amounts to
$$P(|\bar X - 70| \le 0.05) = P(69.5 \le \bar X \le 70.5) \\
= P\left(\frac{69.5 - 70}{3/\sqrt{n}} \le Z \le \frac{70.5 - 70}{3/\sqrt{n}}  \right) = 0.98,$$

where $Z$ has a standard normal distribution. From printed tables of the
standard normal distribution we find that $\frac{70.5 - 70}{3/\sqrt{n}} =2.236.$
Solve for $n$ and round up to the nearest integer.

*Note:* In your Comment, I believe you may misinterpret the term *standard error*.
The standard error of in this situation is $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n}.$
You can view this problem in terms of a 98% confidence interval, in which
you want the *margin of error* $2.236\sigma/\sqrt{n} = 0.5.$ (It is common
to use 95% confidence intervals, but here you are asked for a *98%* CI.)